# How to run a promotional sale for a certain amount of time

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, price

I am wondering how to run a flash sale for my app for a specific amount of time. I know you can do this over a period of days, but can you do it for just a few hours?

For example:

I can announce on social media that my app will be free for only the next 4 hours, so act fast if you want to download it. But after 4 hours it goes back to the original price.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually in iTunes Connect. Simply switch the price to the desired pricing tier and after 4 hours switch it manually back. There is no way to do automatic scheduling besides the „day-frames“ display on ITC.

One thing to remember here (which might be the cause for Apple not to offer „hourly“ scheduling): It can take some time to reflect the correct prices on the store. We ran some tests and the price displayed is actually different from the price the App Store charges you. Usually the „actual price“ (i.e. the one charged) changes pretty quick, but the one displayed (i.e. the most relevant for the customer) can take a couple of hours to display the correct amount.